# Generating QR code in Android using Java

Tags: java, android

Does anyone knows how to generate QR code using Java program? I need to make an application to generate QR code for given details to Android device. Thank you!

Comment: NO IT IS NOT JAVA. It's Java.

Comment: No problem. But if I changed it myself, next time you would write it again like JAVA. Telling the people works better. :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Pet peeve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ZebraCrossing (ZXing), it looks good: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

```
String contents = "Code";
BarCodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarCodeFormat.QR_CODE;

int width = 300;
int height = 300;

MultiFormatWriter barcodeWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
BitMatrix matrix = barcodeWriter.encode(contents, barcodeFormat, width, height);
BufferedImage qrCodeImg = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks.! I'll have a look. :)

Comment: BufferedImage does not seem to be available in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code using [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) an api for java built on top [ZXING](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

```
private Bitmap generateQRCodeFromText(String text) {
        return QRCode.from(text)
                .withSize(QR_CODE_SIZE, QR_CODE_SIZE)
                .bitmap();
    }
```

OR

```
private Bitmap generateQRCodeFromText(String text){
    try {
        QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, QR_CODE_SIZE, QR_CODE_SIZE);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        return bmp;

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or using [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/)

```
 private Bitmap generateQRCodeFromText(String text) {
     try {
      BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
      Bitmap bmp= barcodeEncoder.encodeBitmap("content", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400);
       return bmp;
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```