# Generate a QR Code in an Android Application

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have been trying to generate a QR code using Zxing.  Following the minimal instructions available on the Zxing project site, I was not able to get this integrated into my application.  I have tried following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280352/620197) (as well as many other search results), but `BufferedImage` does not seem to be available in the Android SDK.  In short, Zxing is not playing nice with my application, or the documentation is not fully explaining the process properly.

I am looking for a simple way to pass in a string and generate a QR code image representing the string.  Ant code samples, or even a nudge in the right direction would greatly appreciated.

Comment: `QRCodeEncoder` method `encodeAsBitmap` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DanS The QRCodeEncoder requires a reference to an activity and an intent.  I was hoping to keep it simpler than that.

Comment: The source is available could you just extract what you need?

Comment: Are you opposed to needing internet? Google charts has a rest API that will accept a string and serve you a QR png.

Comment: @Tim Its not my first choice, the api requires building form to send.  I would rather do it on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an application at one point that needed to be able to generate a QR also.

I, like you started with trying to use ZXing to do it. The project is definitely capable of generating the QR image, but I was never able to get it working correctly.

The only integration they offer for QR generating is thru intents, and it just spits your QR into its own blank Activity.

I tried pulling out enough of the project that I'd be able to use the generator classes, but I could never get it working properly.

In the end I decided to go with the google charts api. Since it requires network it wasn't an ideal solution for me, but it was far easier / less complicated, and I was able to actually get it to work.

### Edit:

Since the time of this post I have created a sample project that demonstrates how to download and show QR codes using the Google Image Charts API. The sample project can be located here: https://github.com/FoamyGuy/QRMaker. I hope it can help someone.

Comment: I think thats where I'm heading, but I don't think my boss will like it, since, first glance, it doesn't support https, and there potentially identifiable information that is being encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the frustration of trying to integrate the ZXing library into my code and get rid of the need of having to install the third-party application.  I finally got it to work.

You need to add the `core.jar` file from the latest ZXing release source to your project.  You also need to add two more classes to your package to get it to work.

Just follow this [step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510698/1181911).